# regular expression findall errors

Tags: python, regex, findall

I run the following script

```
a = r'[abc] [abc] [y78]'
paaa = re.compile(r'\[ab.*]')
paaa.findall(a)
```

I obtained

```
['[abc] [abc] [y78]']
```

Why the '[abc]' is missing? The '[abc]' clearly matches the pattern as well. Is there any bug in the python3 re.findall function?

**Clarification:**

Sorry the `paaa` should be `paaa = re.compile(r'\[ab.*\]')` 
What I am looking for is something which will return

```
['[abc]', '[abc]', '[abc] [abc]', '[abc] [abc] [y78]']
```

Basically, any substring matches the pattern.

Comment: If you want to start with any brackets containing `abc`, why wouldn't `[abc] [y78]` be included in your result as well?

Answer (score 2):

The repeated `.` in `[ab.*]` is *greedy* - it'll match as many characters as it can such that those characters are followed by a `]`. So, everything in between the first `[` and the last `]` are matched.

Use lazy repetition instead, with `.*?`:

```
a = r'[abc] [abc] [y78]'
paaa = re.compile(r'\[ab.*?]')
print(paaa.findall(a))
```

> ```
> ['[abc]', '[abc]']
> ```

Comment: Sorry the `paaa` should be `paaa = re.compile(r'\[ab.*\]')` 
What I am looking for is something which will return

    ['[abc]', '[abc]', '[abc] [abc]', '[abc] [abc] [y78]']

Basically, any substring matches the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

You should escape the right square bracket as well, and use non-greedy repeater `*?` in your regex:

```
import re
a = r'[abc] [abc] [y78]'
paaa = re.compile(r'\[ab.*?\]')
print(paaa.findall(a))
```

This outputs:

```
['[abc]', '[abc]']
```

Comment: "You should escape the right square bracket as well" - no need.

Comment: Sorry the `paaa` should be `paaa = re.compile(r'\[ab.*\]')` 
What I am looking for is something which will return

    ['[abc]', '[abc]', '[abc] [abc]', '[abc] [abc] [y78]']

Basically, any substring matches the pattern.